# Add gap between select box and option one

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to add some gaps between the select box and the dropdown list. Here is an example image:

[image: I hope you can see this image]

The upper example is done with some div.

I've tried using some padding and margin but saw no results. Is it not possible to achieve this with select and option tags?

```css
select{
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
select option:disabled{
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
#one{
  margin-top: 1rem;
  padding-top: 1rem;
 }
```

```html
<select name="select" id="select">
  <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select box</option>
  /*need a gap here*/
  <option id="one" value="option-one">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option-two">Option 2</option>
  <option value="option-three">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try option group html tag

```css
select{
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
select option:disabled{
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
select optgroup {
  margin-top:10px;
}
#one{
  margin-top: 1rem;
  padding-top: 1rem;
 }
```

```html
<select name="select" id="select">
  <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select box</option>
  /*need a gap here*/
 <optgroup label="">
  <option id="one" value="option-one">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option-two">Option 2</option>
  <option value="option-three">Option 3</option>
 </optgroup>
</select>
```